# Problems With CSV Export to Open in Excel with AG-GRID, Angular

Tags: angular, csv, hex, export-to-csv, ag-grid

I'm trying to export an grid to CSV, and in one single column i'm dealing with this, in the object composition, i'm sending a String JSON to "this.gridOptions.api.exportDataAsCsv(params);" , in the text file that is exported when i open it, also comes with a string, the way i wanted, like this ("66668E02").

But when i try to open the CSV in the Excel, he sees some HEXs in some lines and transform this ("66668E02") to this  -> (66666800).

I have saw people here using the method "params.processCellCallback" to do some formatting stuff, it can help me deal with this ? There's some way to type a column to tell the excel this must be a string ?

```
//Just a Resumed code structure of my function 
ExportCSV() {

//check here if the grid is empty 

        var params = {
        //name of the file and separator defined here
        };
        params.processCellCallback = function (params) {
         //done here a treatment to eliminate accents
        };
        params.processHeaderCallback = function (params) {
         //done here a treatment to eliminate accents
        };
        this.gridOptions.api.exportDataAsCsv(params);
      }
```

Thanks for the attention !

Comment: I don't understand, you said ```HEXs```. So in the final output (the .csv file) does the string look like ```66666800``` or does it look like ```666668##```?

Comment: Its like this in a text file ("66668E02") and go to this when i open the Excel(66666800).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure the problem is `66668E02` being considered as an HEX but rather as a scientific notation, i.e. `66668*10^-02`, which indeed equals to `66666800`.

To fix this you can try specifying to AgGrid that the concerned column is a text by setting the `filter` parameter to `agTextColumnFilter` in the `colDef`.